# making angular 1.2.13 work with angular-ui

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the following plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/OGwS47cMJgkjxCliAfku?p=preview and I just can't manage to make typeahead work with angular 1.2.13 and angular-ui.

Also in my script I get Error: undefined b in angular.min.js (line 85).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what version of angular-ui are you using

Comment: Use angular's non-minified version to get the debugging started.